# Could not login social account with Web3AuthModalPack which provided by Safe wallet

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core, safe, web3auth

It seems that could not log in Web3AuthModalPack with any social media account, like Google, Facebook, etc.. It only works when I login with MetaMask. Anyone get the clue?

```
    const init = async () => {
      try {
        const web3AuthModalPack = new Web3AuthModalPack(options, [openloginAdapter], modalConfig)

        const safeAuthKit = await SafeAuthKit.init(web3AuthModalPack, {
          txServiceUrl: 'https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global'
        })       

        safeAuthKit.subscribe(ADAPTER_EVENTS.CONNECTED, connectedHandler)

        safeAuthKit.subscribe(ADAPTER_EVENTS.DISCONNECTED, disconnectedHandler)


        console.log("web3AuthModalPack",await web3AuthModalPack.getUserInfo())

      
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    init();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that issue is from that you are not passing the correct options to the Web3AuthModalPack constructor.

The options object should contain the following properties:

clientId: Your Web3Auth client ID.

network: The network you want to connect to.

redirectUri: The URI to redirect to after the user has logged in.

Once you have added these properties to the options object, the Web3AuthModalPack should work as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I find the key to the question is that the Web3AuthModalPack has outdated web3auth dependency. it was version 4.3.0 and it is far more way of nowadays.

Comment: Glad to hear that, so you fixed the issue I think.
So the issue was from t he dependency issue, thanks.

Good luck.